# python- read txt to soup format

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Since I cannot open youtube where I am now and I want to scrape my youtube list, I have downloaded the content of the url:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


url='https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYjSYQBFeM-zQeZFpWeZ_4tnhc3GQWNj8'
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
f1 = open("c:/exp/soup.txt", "w")
f1.write(soup.prettify().encode('utf-8'))
```

First, I cannot read it with:

```
with open('C:/exp/soup.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
print lines
```

And then I don't know how to convert it to a soup file:

```
f1 = open("C:/exp/soup.txt", "r")
f2=BeautifulSoup(f1)
type(f2)
print f2
```

I got nothing printed.

I need to convert it again to a soup file so I can continue parsing the file.

Comment: If `print lines` shows nothing then your file is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can and should pass the file-like object to the `BeautifulSoup` constructor:

```
with open('C:/exp/soup.txt') as f:
   soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser")

print(soup)
```

If you see nothing printed, then the `C:/exp/soup.txt` file is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
url='https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYjSYQBFeM-zQeZFpWeZ_4tnhc3GQWNj8'
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with urlopen(url) as link:
    result = link.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(result)
f1 = open("E:/soup.txt", "wb")
f1.write(soup.prettify().encode('utf-8'))
```

Read from file :

```
with open('E:/soup.txt','rb') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
print(lines)
##you get the whole html
```

Print soup:

```
f1 = open("E:/soup.txt", "r")
f2=BeautifulSoup(f1)
type(f2)
##<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
print(f2)
##prints the whole soup!
```

If in-case you you get an error : "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character.." then its because of your cmd not using 'utf8'. So in cmd prompt type: `chcp 65001` and re-try.